# VSCode - Auto select non-word characters

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to enable auto select non-word characters in Visual Studio code?

Here is the setting in atom.

[image]

This would enable selection of variables like `$foo` or colours `#fff` with just a double click in Atom Editor. And by selection I mean from $ to o in $foo. At the moment when double clicked on `$foo`, VSCode selects only foo.

Is there a way to enable this?

Comment: To the moderator, who flagged to close the question - SO has been the place to ask questions about IDE, custom configurations and settings, terminal invocations for a very long time. If this question gave an impression to be something else, can you please comment so that we can improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`settings.json`

`"editor.wordSeparators"` from default: `~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?` remove symbol

dollar:

```
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
```

sharp:

```
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
```

both:

```
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
```